# How do I set DagreJS edge weights

Tags: dagre

I'm using [DagreJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dagrejs/dagre) to create a directed graph. I'd like some edges to have more "weight" than other (some edges should be shorter and straighter, other edges shouldn't affect the layout at all).

The documentation does list ["weight" as an edge property in the wiki](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre/wiki#configuring-the-layout), but I'm confused about how to use it.

How do I set the weight for specific edges? Can I pass it into the `setEdge` function?